# Question on nonlinear optimal control problem

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

Problem: Given a discrete equation of state
$$x^{k+1} = x^k -u^k,\ u^k \ge 0.$$
Our goal is to drive in $N$ steps the system to the origin, from $x^0$ and minimize the cost function
$$J(x,u) := \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}u^k \ln{u^k}.$$

1. Find the sufficient condition of the existence and the uniqueness of a solution.
2. Find a close loop solution if possible.

My attempt:

1. In my opinion, the condition should be $\nabla^2_u J(x,u) \succ0$ since $J(x,u)$ has a unique stationary point. But it seem obviously from the formula of the function $J$. So, I wonder that if I have any mistakes here.
2. About the question 2, although I have read the theory about this topic a couple of times but I still have a lot of confusion. So, it will be great if you can help me in my first time studying this subject.

Comment: Are there any constraints? Namely, considering the cost function I assume that $u^k\geq0$?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen In this exercise of my lecture note, I do not see any constraint here. But I also think the constraint is $u^k \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your problem into a convex optimization problem.
Let $u = [u_{0}, u_{1}, \dots, u_{N-1}] \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$.
Then the problem can be written as,

$$
\begin{align}
\min_{u} &&&\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} u_{k}\ln u_{k} \\
s.t. &&& u_{k} \geq 0 \quad \forall k\in [0,1,\dots, N-1] \\
&&& \mathbf{1}^{\mathsf{T}}u = x_{0}
\end{align}
$$

The last constraint is enforcing that the $x_N$ will be at the origin.
Now you can use all the tools from optimization to answer if this problem has a solution, i.e., does the sum of strictly convex functions with affine inequality and equality constraints have a solution? For uniqueness, consider what would happen if you had an optimal solution $u^{*}$ and you "swap" the values of $u^{*}_{1}$ and $u^{*}_{2}$. Would this solution also be optimal? Lastly, you can use methods in optimization to find the optimal control input.